# Registering CentOS7 to Red Hat Satellite, host does not show in GUI

Tags: centos, graphical-user-interface, satellite

Good day all

Having followed (for the most part) the instructions from this link(https://therootuser.com/2017/11/16/adding-centos-server-satellite-6-2/), I was able to get a CentOS 7 server registered to Satellite. Unfortunately, while I am able to pull packages etc, the CentOS host does not show up in the Satellite GUI. What might I be missing?

All steps below were followed on a freshly installed OS, for both Satellite and the CentOS client.

Versions:
Satellite 6.7 (on RHEL 7.8)
CentOS 7 (client)

Steps to configure:

- Add GPG keys
- Created CentOS7 base, extras, updates, peel repositories (and associate GPG keys)
- Created product with associated repos
- Create Content View, Environment, Activation Key with the appropriate associations

Steps to register:

- yum install subscription-manager (while the default internet-facing repos are enabled)
- rpm -Uvh https:///pub/katello-ca-consumer-latest.noarch.rpm
- cd /etc/yum.repos.d; mkdir old; mv nexus* old; yum clean all (Move all old .repo files out, so they don't get used)
- subscription-manager register --org="" --activationkey="<my activation key"

Registration output:

```
The system has been registered with ID: 2cce9838-3d59-4daa-b135-6c09d9676ee4
The registered system name is: centos01-test-bry.platform.is
No products installed.

# subscription-manager list
No installed products to list

# subscription-manager status
+-------------------------------------------+
   System Status Details
+-------------------------------------------+
Overall Status: Current

System Purpose Status: Not Specified

# subscription-manager repos
+----------------------------------------------------------+
    Available Repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo
+----------------------------------------------------------+
Repo ID:   Dimension_Data_centos7_base_centos7_base
Repo Name: centos7_base
Repo URL:  <URL>
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   Dimension_Data_centos7_base_epel_centos7
Repo Name: epel_centos7
Repo URL:  <URL>
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   Dimension_Data_centos7_base_centos7_updates
Repo Name: centos7_updates
Repo URL:  <URL>
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   centos7_base_centos7_extras
Repo Name: centos7_extras
Repo URL:  <URL>
Enabled:   1
```

Contents of `/var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log` on a newly registered system:

```
2020-09-17 09:36:48,849 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=identity_cert ca_dir=/etc/rhsm/ca/ insecure=False
2020-09-17 09:36:48,863 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=identity_cert ca_dir=/etc/rhsm/ca/ insecure=False
2020-09-17 09:36:48,863 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=none
2020-09-17 09:36:48,883 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=none
2020-09-17 09:36:53,086 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @managerlib.py:72 - Consumer created: centos01-test-bry.platform.is (77d21990-95e0-4188-b5dd-64b04eb3566c)
2020-09-17 09:36:53,089 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=identity_cert ca_dir=/etc/rhsm/ca/ insecure=False
2020-09-17 09:36:54,854 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @entcertlib.py:131 - certs updated:
Total updates: 1
Found (local) serial# []
Expected (UEP) serial# [3013788056154176091]
Added (new)
  [sn:3013788056154176091 (CentOS 7 ALL Repos,) @ /etc/pki/entitlement/3013788056154176091.pem]
Deleted (rogue):
  <NONE>
2020-09-17 09:36:55,199 [INFO] subscription-manager:8688:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=identity_cert ca_dir=/etc/rhsm/ca/ insecure=False
2020-09-17 09:36:55,386 [INFO] rhsmd:8700:MainThread @connection.py:905 - Connection built: host=<Satellite FQDN> port=443 handler=/rhsm auth=identity_cert ca_dir=/etc/rhsm/ca/ insecure=False
```

As mentioned, a `yum install` works fine, but the host does not show up in the GUI.

As one piece of diagnosis, I had come across the relevance of the files in /etc/pki/products on a RHEL system years back, and I attempted to put copies from a RHEL server onto the CentOS client, with the following result:

```
# subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Software Collections (for RHEL Server)
Product ID:     201
Version:        3
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Not Subscribed
Status Details: Not supported by a valid subscription.
Starts:
Ends:

Product Name:   Red Hat Satellite Capsule
Product ID:     269
Version:        6.3
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Not Subscribed
Status Details: Not supported by a valid subscription.
Starts:
Ends:

Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Product ID:     69
Version:        7.8
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Not Subscribed
Status Details: Not supported by a valid subscription.
Starts:
Ends:
```

The behaviour changes but it "sees" the server as a RHEL system.

I've also checked out this link, without any result: [CentOS 7 with Red Hat Satellite 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/678373/centos-7-with-red-hat-satellite-6)

Any assistance would be appreciated, please let me know if I can provide any additional information.